# Overwrite my local changes in TortoiseSVN from latest version

Tags: java, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Lets say I did a check out, edited some stuff and realized I want to re-download the repository code and overwrite my local changes without commiting them.

At the time of checkout file version was 100 in SVN,I  done some edit and now I want to take latest version from SVN and overwrite the changes I have done. Now the version of the file in SVN is 103,I want this 103 version in my local only and overwrite the chnges i have done.

In some previous post it was suggested that use SVN revert but According to me Svn revert will give me the version of code I have checked out like in my case I checked out 100 version so it will get the 100 version and overwrite it not the latest one i.e 103.
Please help.Using tortiose SVN.

**NOTE** -this question is already posted but answer are not setisfectory thats why I am posting it again

[Here is the link of post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633278/how-do-i-overwrite-my-local-changes-in-tortoisesvn)

Comment: why not delete the contents of your local copy and do a update?

Comment: But every time we could not do that for whole project right,bcz we don't remember how many file got changed at the time of POC,so At the end you want to update your project with latest code in SVN after discarding your changes?

Comment: Please clarify your last comment, I don't understand what you mean. What is POC? Discarding your changes == deleting the local project contents

Comment: Why are those answers on the other question not satisfactory? You are trying to do two things: remove your changes, and get the latest changes. So tell SVN to do both, using two commands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I overwrite my local changes in TortoiseSVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633278/how-do-i-overwrite-my-local-changes-in-tortoisesvn)

Comment: Not only are those answers satisfactory, they include the sensible advice to check the changes (e.g. with Tortoise Diff) before you discard your changes.

Comment: You say revert takes you back to the revision you started with, which is right, but the answers to the other post then say ‘do an update if you want the most recent revision’, which is what you say you want. **Problem solved.**

Comment: @PJTraill nut update command will not discard your changes on the file,I want discard the changes and update the file with the latest version

Comment: @jwsc POc- implementing some new fature in project

Comment: Update command will not discard your changes. A delete will.

Comment: @jwsc: POC probably stands for Proof Of Concept, i.e. demonstrate feasibility without worrying too much about quality.

Comment: @Rahulray: What don’t you get: “I want (to) discard the changes” that is **revert** “and update the file with the latest version” that is **update**.

Comment: @PJTraill got it,then we need to run two operation first revert then update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your local copy and get update from SVN , you will get current version of copy from SVN

Comment: is this is the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

As already posted in the comments, The obvious solution would be removing your local copy and make an update from your repository. This way you forget about local changes (obviously, you remove them) and you get the current revision of your project (through the "update" command). I would say that this is an easy solution.

If you think we got something wrong with your problem, please edit your Question to clarify.